# SharePoint Exception - Exception occurred while creating an SPIdentityContext from SPUserToken

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

> Exception occurred while creating an SPIdentityContext from SPUserToken '34c1b4e00000000034000000efeeebea010000000c00000000000000dfdedbda0100000000000000010100000000000000000000'. System.NotSupportedException: Not supported in Windows authentication mode.
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPIdentityContext.Create(SPUserToken token, Boolean isShareByLinkGuestUser) StackTrace: 
>    at onetnative.dll: (sig=37460b31-4453-4365-92f5-3a11c267be48|2|onetnative.pdb, offset=28F56)
>    at onetnative.dll: (offset=15735)

What does this exception means? How to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

I did some research for you despite the lack of information.
What I found is people get this error when working with Workflow Manager workflows (SharePoint 2013 workflows).

So I recommend that you review the status of your Workflow Manager setup.
Confirm that your App and Management and Subscriptions service applications are configured and functional.
Confirm that your web application is configured for claims authentication.

If you still have issues please provide more information.

Comment: Can kindly let me know what additional information is expected? I have a poor understanding about workflows. My web application is configured with Claims.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot or details of what you do when the error appears?  are there specific steps in the workflow that deal with user details?